# Material UI Table- Change font colour based on price

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a table where when the numbers are negative the font colour must be red and if it is positive, it must be green.
I have a similar table that works fine but I am having trouble with this one.
If anybody could help me I would appreciate it a lot.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Table from '@mui/material/Table';
import TableBody from '@mui/material/TableBody';
import TableCell, { tableCellClasses } from '@mui/material/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@mui/material/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@mui/material/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@mui/material/TableRow';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';

export default function MiniTable(data) {
  if (data.data && Object.keys(data.data).length === 0) return <div />;
  data.data.reverse();

  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table sx={{ minWidth: 700 }} size="small">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <StyledTableCell>Date</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="right">Budget</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="right">Total Margin</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="right">CPC</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="right">Bid Target</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="right">Spend</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="right">Total Profit</StyledTableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {data.data.map((row) => (
            <StyledTableRow key={row.name}>
              <StyledTableCell component="th" scope="row">
                {row.date.split('T')[0]}
              </StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right">${row.budget.toFixed(2)}</StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right">${row.totalMargin}</StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right">${row.cpc.toFixed(2)}</StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right">${row.bidTarget.toFixed(2)}</StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right">${row.spend.toFixed(2)}</StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right">${row.totalProfit.toFixed(2)}</StyledTableCell>
            </StyledTableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}
```

Change the font colour based on information